# how to edit in turtlebot _description package

Tags: gazebo, simulation, turtlebot, turtlebot-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ,

I am successfully build a map in rviz for a simple_office.world. now I want to edit in robot description to remove gyro from the robot model that loaded to gazebo.

There is a package turtlebot_description/urdf/files.urdf.xacro ... so I think The gyro is defined in turtlebot_body.urdf.xacro, but I can not edit on it ..

How to edit it to remove gyro part .. also want to know if there is another files I have to edit on

I want to remove gyro, because I do not have a gyro on my real iRobot Create base..

any suggestion

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57658/how-to--edit-in-turtlebot-_description-package/) by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-03-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2013-03-10**:
Which distro are you on Amal?

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2013-03-10**:
I do not understand what you mean by distro ?!

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2013-03-10**:
I am use ROS feurte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Amal!

You probably have installed the turtlebot_description package via a debian package. Thus, it was installed as sudo and if you want to edit it, you need to use sudo as well.

A better way would be to download the turtlebot_description package as source and copy it into your workspace. Remember to modify your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH in order to use the source install and not the debian package.

Have a look at this wiki entry for more details: http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2013-03-12**:
I can edit now on this files .. what files do you think I have to edit on to remove gyro ?!

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-03-12**:
If you are only concerned about the gyro simulation, commenting out "<turtlebot_sim_imu/>" will probably be enough. If needed also remove the gyro link and joint.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-03-19**:
@amal, please mark your questions as answered - click the check symbol of the answer - if your problem has been solved. Thank you!